# How to debug through .NET Framework source code?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I've followed the steps outlined in http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx to enable source debugging of the .NET Framework, and I had it working in the past.  Now that I'm using .NET 3.5 SP1, it seems to have stopped working.  Beyond the steps in the blog entry I just mentioned, what special steps can I make to get source debugging working again?

Comment: +1. I'm also having this problem.

Comment: I'm unable to debug Framework Source on Visual Studio SP1.  It used to work on my machine.  I initially had Windbg and Visual Studio caching symbols to the same directory but now I've moved the VS.NET cache to it's own directory to force it to redownload the symbols.

Comment: My output window states:
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSourceView.XmlDataSourceView'

Here are some excerpts from my environment

Options Debugging --> General
 unchecked -Enable Just My Code
 checked - Enable .NET Framework source stepping
 checked - Enable Source Server Support
  checked - Print source server diagnostic messages to the Output window

Options Debugging --> Symbols
 checked - symbol file (.pdb) locations: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
 checked - search the above locations only when symbols are loaded manually.

Comment: Modules window:
 System.Web.dll C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll Yes N/A Symbols loaded. C:\managedSymbols\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\System.Web.pdb\DBE79CC9E37744848AFF0F27BA61686C1\System.Web.pdb 10 2.0.50727.3082 (QFE.050727-3000) 11/25/2008 12:03 AM 65F20000-66A63000 [6848]

System.Web.pdb size 912,384 bytes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to Step in to .net framework source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886009/unable-to-step-in-to-net-framework-source-code)

Comment: @Alex, I think you should mark the *other* question as a dupe of this one, seeing as this one came first, and has more answers too.

Comment: @Andrew: Whoops - thanks. There are a few dupes around this topic.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2022 you can find the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186080/how-can-i-step-into-microsofts-net-framework-source-code/78140390#78140390)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is broken in the latest GDR, Microsoft needs to fix it

Comment: Ah... any KB article on the problem or any other reference?

Comment: Sadly no :(  I'll try to complain some more.

Comment: Is this still broken? Also ... what about .NET 4.0? I've been trying to debug into ContentPresenter for either WPF 3.5 SP1 or WPF 4.0 and I can't get it to work.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work for .NET 4.0 by simply downloading the .NET 4 symbols/source from http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx. I never could get it to work for .NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: General Distribution Release, a release intended for a wide audience (almost always a security-related release)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when I upgraded to .NET 3.5 sp1. It seems like it's very simplified with the sp1 release. Now you only have to check the "Enable .NET framework source stepping" (which automatically unchecks "Enable just my code"). You don't have to change anything in the "Symbols" settings anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to refresh your downloaded symbols. In the Symbol settings dialog you specify a cache directory where symbols are cached. Since you have upgraded your .NET framework, therefore, the symbols cached there are most probably the older ones which won't work with the newer dlls. Just clear your directory and then download symbols for .NET 3.5 SP1 again.

Comment: I have this problem and .NET 3.5 SP1 is the first version I've tried with.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging didn't work for me when I first followed those steps. I deleted symbol directory and removed all settings from Options -> Debugging -> Symbols and it worked.

- Uncheck "Enable Just My Code"
- Check "Enable .NET Framework source stepping"
- Check "Enable source server support"
- Don't add anything to Debugging -> Symbols

Works just fine on Windows 7 x64 with Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Comment: Why don't add anything into Symbols?

Comment: It didn't work when I had them. When there is nothing in there it downloads the correct ones.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Of course ... it is over a year later. It downloaded the symbols, but when I try to double click a stack frame to debug the .NET Framework ... it says that no source code is available.

Comment: @cplotts: the same for me. Anyone knows the proper way to set it up correctly?