# How to debug a low level system exception in Visual Studio 2003?

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2003, nullreferenceexception

I have spend two days of work trying to figure out a weird problem is happening on my PC.

I am debugging a quite complex old application written in .NET 1.1 that is made by an mdi container that load at runtime different assemblies that implements custom interface as windows form mdi child.

The problem is that on my PC (i tried on other PC and it works) the application throws a strange exception. This is not generated by managed code, it is probably a RARE condition that cause the framework self to through the exception.

I am trying to isolate the problem by commenting code by code but it's very long task.

Do you have any idea how can I identify faster the cause of this undesired exception?

The exception is **NullReferenceException** and this is the stack trace:

```
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods+IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   at MyAPP in xxxx.vb:line 26
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [Enable .NET framework source stepping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373796/how-to-debug-through-net-framework-source-code) and debug into the framework code. Maybe this helps identifying the cause.

Comment: hi Daniel, unfortunately I think the page suggested is for Visual Studio 2008 or above

Comment: @marco, Visual Studio 2008 Express would solve that problem. ;)

Comment: I overlooked the VS2003 tag ... but as Simon suggested, the express edition should do.

Comment: @simon

I cannot convert the project to VS2008/Framework 2.0 or above. Also because I tried that and the problem does not happen anymore. It is something related to Framework 1.1

Comment: Can't VS2008 target .NET 1.1, too?

Comment: @daniel

unfortunately not :)